# How to set multiple headers in fitnesse?

Tags: fixtures, fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

I have a requirement to set more than one header while testing `REST` calls using `Fitnesse` Client.

Tried with

```
|setHeader|!-myheader1 : value1-!!-myheader2:value2-!|

|setHeader|!-myheader1 : value1-!\n\r!-myheader2:value2-!|

|setHeader|!-myheader1 : value1\n\rmyheader2:value2-!|
```

All of these are not working..

References used :

http://smartrics.blogspot.in/2008/08/get-fitnesse-with-some-rest.html

http://tlotd.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/fitnesse-with-restfixture/

Could anyone please tell me the correct way to pass two headers in fitnesse client ?

Answer (score 3):

RestFixture supports the ability to set multiple headers, one per line, as following:

```
| setHeaders | !- name1 : value 1
name2 : value2 -! |
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have now rewritten the answer